# What is the problem here?

Tags: configuration, connection

```
2/3/19, 12:27:36.657 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/3/19, 12:27:36.657 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/3/19, 12:27:36.657 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/3/19, 12:27:36.657 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/3/19, 12:27:36.658 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/3/19, 12:27:36.658 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
2/3/19, 12:27:36.661 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\0119\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
2/3/19, 12:27:37.210 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
2/3/19, 12:27:37.668 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
2/3/19, 12:27:38.250 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
2/3/19, 12:27:38.523 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
2/3/19, 12:27:42.730 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
2/3/19, 12:27:42.557 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs 
2/3/19, 12:27:44.503 [WARN] Our clock is 5 hours, 32 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2019-02-03 18:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
2/3/19, 12:27:44.504 [WARN] Received microdesc flavor consensus with skewed time (CONSENSUS): It seems that our clock is behind by 5 hours, 32 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
2/3/19, 12:27:44.504 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 40%: Loading authority key certs. (Clock skew -19938 in microdesc flavor consensus from CONSENSUS; CLOCK_SKEW; count 2; recommendation warn; host ? at ?) 
2/3/19, 12:27:44.504 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
2/3/19, 12:27:44.505 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/3/19, 12:27:44.534 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
2/3/19, 12:27:44.566 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/3/19, 12:27:44.566 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
```

Comment: quoting from your question: `Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings!` - have you done that? ...at least if so, a little bit more context than just posting the error-log would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

the messages are there for a reason... please read it and act accordingly:

> Our clock is 5 hours, 32 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2019-02-03 18:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings!

it seems that your clock is out of sync... please try to connect again (to rule out if it was a server issue), if you get the same error message again set the correct time on your machine. - IIRC your hardware clock should be in UTC!